# pkgbuild error when adding component

Tags: macos, pkgbuild

I have the following directory structure within my current working directory (CWD):

- MyAppBundle/MyApp.app
- MyAppBundle.plist

MyAppBundle.plist contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>BundleHasStrictIdentifier</key>
      <true/>
      <key>BundleIsRelocatable</key>
      <true/>
      <key>BundleIsVersionChecked</key>
      <true/>
      <key>BundleOverwriteAction</key>
      <string>upgrade</string>
      <key>RootRelativeBundlePath</key>
      <string>MyApp.app</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
</plist>
```

When I run the following command from the CWD:

```
pkgbuild --root ./MyAppBundle --component-plist 'MyAppBundle.plist' MyApp.pkg
```

... I get the following output:

```
pkgbuild: Reading components from MyAppBundle.plist
pkgbuild: Adding component at MyApp.app
pkgbuild: error: (null)
```

Comment: PS: My app was built using C++/Cocoa if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've figured it out. If I add `--identifier <unique identifier>` to the `pkgbuild` command above, it works.